# how to stop yum from asking for pdate directory

Tags: rpm, yum

I used

```
createrepo -update ...
```

by mistake when I meant `--update`.  Now, yum complains all the time about `pdate` directory not being there.  Even though I checked that string is not in `yum.conf` nor in any `.repo` files, it is still complaining about it.

I also removed the `metadeta` directory by hand and recreated `createrepo` correctly.

It is still complaining.

How do I make yum forget that `pdate`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone has this same issue, what happened here was that using the -u flag changed the base URL for the repository to ./pdate (because apparently anything after -u is interpreted as a baseURL value.)

The easy fix is to simply change the baseURL to the value it should be (http://something.com/repo/6/x86_64 or what have you) by running:

createrepo -u $baseURL --update /path/to/repository

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also cleaned (nuked) the cache directory mentioned in the "files" section of the man page.  This still did not work.

Finally, I noticed that there is this thing called "yum clean", it is mentioned in the man page but not quite sure what it is.

However, I did run

```
yum clean all
```

and that finally worked to clean the erroneous (-u)pdate directory